# QGIS map composer changing legend position when exporting atlas as images

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend, atlas

I am having an issue when exporting atlas map series to image. In each map the position of the legend is jumping around by a few cm. I have the position referenced under item properties to the bottom right corner which I thought would mean the legend expands and contracts upward and left as the legend contents change between maps. Instead the whole legend seems to move around sometimes covering up other information.

Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix the position by copying the X and Y values without the `mm` under the tab Position and size and paste them by clicking on Data Defined Override and go to paste as you can see below or go to Edit and paste the number only there:

[image]

After pasting the number, it should be marked in yellow color

[image]

Do this process for both X and Y which will fix the position of the legend.

Comment: not seeming to work, perhaps there is something wrong

Comment: Try to fix the width and height also. Even if the data in the legend changed the size will not be changed in this case.

Comment: Nope, still moving around. I'm not sure if the data defined buttons are supposed to be red now? sorry i'm new to this and cant work out how to post screenshots

Comment: I have edited the expression to deleted the mm symbol and with x, y and the height and width all fixed it works, however there is excess space in the legend on many maps that are not displaying as many layers. Maybe this I gotta live with?

Comment: No, it should be yellow. Copy only the number without `mm` for X and Y and paste each one for its corresponding field.

Comment: If you fixed the the width and height, clear them as they are not necessary. Only X and Y are necessary.

Comment: with the width and height not fixed it is moving all over the place again

Comment: In this case keep them fixed, but you may need to test other reference points. For example, use lower left instead of upper left. Also, sometimes you need to reduce the spacing between the legend items to prevent them overlapping other items in the maps.

Answer (score 3):

I observe the same issue happening when the checkbox "*Main properties > Resize to fit contents*" is checked.

Also I can observe that the `Y` position on page `n` is what should have been set as `Y` position calculated for page `n-1`.

For example is the legend was tall on page 2, and short on page 3 then it is floating high on page 3 instead of being anchored at the bottom of the page where I want it.

The solution above won't fix the issue, in my case. The only way that I found is unchecking "*Resize to fit contents*"

Page 1, tall legend:

[image: Page 1, tall legend]

Page 2, short legend:

[image: Page 2, short legend]

Page 3, tall legend:

[image: Page 3, tall legend]

I'm using QGIS 2.18.24 on OS X El Capitan.

Any hep would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After check and test, i confirm that this bug is fix with qgis 3.28 !

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/37566

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/49747