# QGIS composer changing legend position when exporting

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend, atlas

I'm observing the same issue seen in [QGIS map composer changing legend position when exporting atlas as images](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/265163) It is happening when the checkbox "*Main properties > Resize to fit contents*" is checked.

Also I can observe that the `Y` position on page `n` is what should have been set as `Y` position calculated for page `n-1`.

For example is the legend was tall on page 2, and short on page 3 then it is floating high on page 3 instead of being anchored at the bottom of the page where I want it.

The upvoted answer in [QGIS map composer changing legend position when exporting atlas as images](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/265163) won't fix the issue in my case. The only way that I found is unchecking "*Resize to fit contents*", which is not satisfactory for me.

Page 1, tall legend:

[image: Page 1, tall legend]

Page 2, short legend:

[image: Page 2, short legend]

Page 3, tall legend:

[image: Page 3, tall legend]

I'm using QGIS 2.18.24 on OS X El Capitan.

I have the Legend properly anchored, here is the preview of page 2:

[image: Legend anchorage, page 2]

Answer (score 2):

From the images provided, I can see that you checked `Show contents inside current atlas feature` and you are using a reference point of `upper left` to anchor the legend.

However, since the contents of the legend is changing every page, using a reference point of `upper left` is not the correct choice. You need to choose a reference point of `bottom left`.

[image]

In this case the legend will extend to the upper direction rather than the lower direction.

Also you can fix the legend position by copying the X and Y values without the unit under the tab `Position and size`, and paste them by clicking on `Data Defined Override`.

Here is the output:

Page 1:

[image]

Page 2:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for not adding this precision to my question, I do have it anchored to the bottom left corner, see my edit in the question.

Comment: @ClemRz Try to fix the x position not just y and see if this can solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you but I already tried it, it's not an option for me: "The upvoted answer in the provided reference won't fix the issue, in my case"

Answer (score 0):

After check and test, i confirm that this bug is fix with qgis 3.28 !

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/37566

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/49747